# Repeating sound until video complete in MediaMuxer

Tags: android, mediamuxer

I am adding sound in existing video using MediaMuxer.i Successfully added audio to video.but the audio plays only ones after that video remain silent.I want to repeat audio until the video completed.following is my code to muxing audio and video.I used android MediaMuxer to perform this task.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
private void muxing(String srcVideo, String audio)
{
    String outputFile = "";

    try
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final2.mp4");
        file.createNewFile();
        outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

        MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();;
        videoExtractor.setDataSource(srcVideo);

        MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        audioExtractor.setDataSource(audio);

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount());
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount());

        MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

        audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString());

        boolean sawEOS = false;
        int frameCount = 0;
        int offset = 100;
        int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
        ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


        videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

        muxer.start();

        while (!sawEOS) {
            videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


            if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                sawEOS = true;
                videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

            } else {
                videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                videoExtractor.advance();


                frameCount++;
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        boolean sawEOS2 = false;
        int frameCount2 = 0;
        while(!sawEOS2)
        {
            frameCount2++;

            audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

            if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                sawEOS2 = true;
                audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                audioExtractor.advance();

                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        muxer.stop();
        muxer.release();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please help me how to add repeating audio to video.there is no documetation avilable to perform this task in developer site.Thanks

Comment: Once the audio source is exhausted, you need to restart/reset it so you can easily the same samples back out again. As you're adding the duplicate samples, you need to make sure `audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs` continues to be incremented in a uniform way, such that each audio samples appears at a time following the one before it.

Comment: Please give me some code or example